# RTK Query hooks - preventing polling to auto refetch when arg change

Tags: reactjs, token, polling, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to refresh a token in a Query hook, with the polling feature every 9 seconds:

```
"/App.tsx"
..
...
const [storedToken, setStoredToken] = useState(getStoredToken());

const { data, error, refetch } = useRefreshUserQuery(storedToken, {
   pollingInterval: 9000,
   // refetchOnMountOrArgChange: false // -> This has no effect
});
...
..
```

The problem is, it re-fetches instantly when the token is set with setStoredToken(token). The new token is passed as argument to the Query hook `storedToken` and refetch immediately (like an infinite loop).

That would be pretty neat to be able to do this. Is there any better way to refresh a token with polling?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that issue is nothing to solve on RTK-Q level - it's a pretty common and expected "limitation" of hooks and rendering lifecycle architecture. And I feel that RTK-Q polling just won't fit your requirements here, of course, that you are trying to achieve - it's not actually polling in common sense. At least - it's conditional polling, which needs some more logic)

So I would solve this just by debouncing and useEffect:

```
  const [storedToken, setStoredToken] = useState<string>(getStoredToken());
  const [tokenDebounced] = useDebounce(storedToken, 9000);
  const { data } = useRefreshUserQuery(tokenDebounced);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setStoredToken(data);
      // console.log(newToken);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

The `useEffect` content and `data` content may differ, but the overall idea should be clear.

useDebounce is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce,
but your own implementations should work the same if you have some defined already.

Another idea, touching you AUTH setup a bit - is just avoid

```
const [storedToken, setStoredToken] = useState<string>(getStoredToken());
```

the part at all, and keep `useRefreshUserQuery()` without params.

Most likely and common is to store the token in `localStorage` or redux\other store, and define new `baseQuery`, based on `fetchBaseQuery` that will set header and\or to include cookies with `credentials: "include"` with a token from `localStorage` or redux\other store. Definitely, you will need to store it during the first AUTH then.

I think RTK-Q auth example reveals this case in some way also:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#authentication

After you'll avoid that `useState` and query hook param - you'll be able to use polling with no issues:

```
const { data, error, refetch } = useRefreshUserQuery(undefined ,{
   pollingInterval: 9000,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"Polling" here means "fetch X seconds after I have data", but of course you have to get the first data itself - and that is that first fetch. If you prevent that, polling will also never start.

Tbh., this is kind of a weird requirement and doing it like this will fill your cache with dozens of state entries.

I'd do something a little differently - solve it in the [endpoint lifecycle](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates#using-the-oncacheentryadded-lifecycle).

This is untested pseudocode and you'll need to adjust it a bit:

```
function waitFor(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("waited"), ms))
}


currentToken: build.query({
  query() {
    // whatever you need for the first token here
  },
async onCacheEntryAdded(
        arg,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        try {
          // wait for the initial query to resolve before proceeding
          await cacheDataLoaded

          while (true) {
            const result = await Promise.race(waitFor(9000), cacheEntryRemoved)
            if (result !== "waited") {
              // cache entry was removed, stop the loop
              break
            }
            // make a fetch call to get a new token here
            const newToken = fetch(...)

            updateCachedData((oldData) => newToken)
          }
      },
})
```

and then just

```js
const result = useCurrentTokenQuery()
```

in your component

Comment: "this will fill your cache with dozens of state entries" right... especially that the API returns a lot of other stuff alongside the token. Thanks for the suggestion phry, I will try.